# Python 3.9 Initializing constants of class with static methods yields error

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods, static-members, mysql-loadfile

I'm trying to create a class in python3.9 to dynamily load constant values of the class by loading a file from a static method as follows:

```
class SQLQueries(object):

    CLIPAPP = SQLQueries.load_query_statement('clinapp.sql')

    MENSALIDADES = SQLQueries.load_query_statement('mensalidades.sql')

    SINISTRO = SQLQueries.load_query_statement('sinistro.sql')


    @staticmethod
    def load_query_statement(sql_file, format_params=None):
        curr_dir = os.getcwd()
        sql_dir = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'queries', sql_file)
        with open(sql_dir, 'r') as sql:
            query = sql.read()
            query = query.format(format_params)
        return query
```

But when doing this, it yields the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-ddf4f8beb954> in <module>
----> 1 class SQLQueries(object):
      2 
      3     CLIPAPP = SQLQueries.load_query_statement('clinapp.sql')
      4 
      5     MENSALIDADES = SQLQueries.load_query_statement('mensalidades.sql')

<ipython-input-49-ddf4f8beb954> in SQLQueries()
      1 class SQLQueries(object):
      2 
----> 3     CLIPAPP = SQLQueries.load_query_statement('clinapp.sql')
      4 
      5     MENSALIDADES = SQLQueries.load_query_statement('mensalidades.sql')

NameError: name 'SQLQueries' is not defined
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: `SQLQueries` *doesn't exist inside the class definition statement*.

Comment: But more importantly, what is the *point* of this class? It just has a bunch of class variables and a staticmethod. This should *not be a class*. The simplest solution would just be to make this `staticmethod` a module-level function.

Answer (score -1):

> how can I fix that?

By not doing it.

First, you're misunderstanding the *execution model* of Python in three ways:

- Control flow aside, Python code executes linearly top to bottom
- the "body" of a class statement *is executed code*, there's some magic surrounding the execution environment (the *scope*) but that's about it
- the class object is not created until the class body has fully executed

In essence,

```py
class Foo:
    ...
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```py
def Foo_body():
    ...
    return locals()
Foo = type('Foo', (object,), Foo_body())
```

From this you can see two things:

- It's impossible for a class body statement to refer to something *following* it in the class body
- "methods" are nothing more than a bog-standard regular function until after the body has executed fully

Second, static methods are rarely if ever *useful* in Python, and as the old [Python is not Java](https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) essay noted almost 20 years ago:

> A static method in Java does not translate to a Python classmethod.  [...] The idiomatic translation of a Java static method is usually a module-level function, not a classmethod or staticmethod.

So

- if you're writing a staticmethod, you should not
- if you're writing a classmethod, you should consider really hard whether that's actually needed e.g. you may need to override a non-default constructor (that's essentially the use-case)

Otherwise... just write a function. Functions are cool. Here you should just write a function, there is no reason for a staticmethod.

I'm not sure the class itself is even useful, frankly.